# JavaScript - change font color on certain index

Tags: javascript, html

I have this long string and I want a part of it transformed into white colour using only JavaScript.

Example 1:

```
var string = document.getElementById("subtitle").innerHTML; //returns the string

var i = string.indexOf("("); //returns 80
var j = string.indexOf(")"); //return 93
```

Example 2: I can get the wanted text but I don't know how to change it white

```
var string = document.getElementById("subtitle").innerHTML; //returns the string

var i = string.indexOf("(");
var j = string.substring(i, string.indexOf(")")+1); //return the exact string I want to paint white
//j.paintWhite(); how?
```

I would like to paint all the characters between positions 80 and 93 (or selected as shown in example #2) white. How can I do it?

Comment: All of your answers work perfectly but not in my case. I have made a screenshot of what I'm trying to colour white. I NEED those numbers to calculate in steps that follow. If I colour them white they won't be seen by the user. Screenshot: http://shrani.si/f/2s/em/42qq7E5B/capture.png -> I'm trying to get rid of that "(+0.08 €)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an html container for that text where you can specify a style attribute.

also, **do not use the variable name `string` as it is reserved to the language**

In order to do that, I would recommend using jQuery, as it is a bit easier.

But if you don't want to, you can do:

```
var text = document.getElementById("subtitle").innerHTML;
var cut = text.split("(");
var cut2 = cut[1].split(")");
var colored = cut[0] + '<span style="color:#fff;">('+cut2[0]+')</span>'+cut2[1];
document.getElementById("subtitle").innerHTML = colored;
```

Comment: +1 to point out the issue with the variable name which I didn't see

Answer (score 1):

if you assume "transformed into white colour" is doing

```
<span style="color:#fff">MY_TEXT_HERE</span>
```

then you could try the following with arrays:

```
var string = document.getElementById("subtitle").innerHTML;
var arr1 = string.split('(');
var arr2 = arr1[1].split(')');
var finalString = arr1[0] + '<span style="color:#fff">' + arr2[0] + '</span>' + arr2[1];
```

Comment: Is it possible to change colour to white from a certain index? Example: Index is 40. I want everything white beyond that point..

Comment: i don't know your requirements but why not to have special span/div inside your element and then reference its style property directly: document.getElementById("subtitle_child_that_i_want_to_make_white").style.color = ...

Comment: @shish Just use the substring method to implement it given the index

Answer (score 0):

You must modify the inner Html of the element so it has a text element nested with a defind style.

http://jsfiddle.net/gsexxsbs/

```
var element = document.getElementById("subtitle");

var htmlText = element.innerHTML; 

var i = htmlText.indexOf("(");
var j = htmlText.indexOf(")")+1;

var redText = htmlText.substring(i, j);

element.innerHTML = htmlText.substring(0,i)+"<a style='color:red;'>"+redText+"</a>"+htmlText.substring(j);
```